# What is the etymology of "todger"?

Tags: etymology, slang, colloquialisms

What is the etymology of "todger"? My Concise OED is rather vague:

> ORIGIN 1950s: of unknown origin (also **tadger**)

"Tadger" is just listed as a "Variant spelling of TODGER"

---

Other references are no better:

- [Wiktionary adds nothing but some very recent examples](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/todger) -- nothing back to the 1950's.
- [The Online Etymology Dictionary has no entry at all](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?&search=todger).
- [Google search is not helpful](https://www.google.com/search?q=etymology%20todger), so far.

But, Google Ngram Viewer has some interesting results (click images for larger views):

1. ["todger" has a huge relative spike in 1722](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=todger,tadger&year_start=1000&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=0) (Update: MετάEd points out that this is due to an OCR error and misleading "Normalization" of the graph by Google.):

   [image: todger, lower-case, big picture]
2. [Recent history](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=todger,tadger&year_start=1850&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=0) is interesting and doesn't really support the 1950's origin of "todger":

   [image: todger, lower-case, more recent]
3. If we go [with proper names](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=todger,tadger,Todger,Tadger&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0), it gets more interesting:

   [image: todger, name-case, big picture]
4. [More recently, name-case](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=todger,tadger,Todger,Tadger&year_start=1850&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=0) swamps lower-case, but is mostly flat after 1868, except for a slight blip in the **1940's** (not 50's).

   [image: todger, name-case, more recent]
5. [Upper-case (TODGER, TADGER) is not found.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=TODGER,TADGER&year_start=1000&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=0)

---

So, what really is the origin of "todger"? Is it possible that it has an eponymous origin?

Comment: When I click throught that 1722 spike it seems "todger" is actually an OCR mistake: the word was "Lodger". This is also true of the 1891 spike. So I am not inclined to doubt OED on the basis of this search.

Comment: @MετάEd, good to know. I'd forgotten about the "detail" links at the bottom.  Interesting that 1 hit (maybe 2, Google isn't clear), in 1 book, gives such a large spike.

Comment: One hit is a larger percentage at a time when fewer total books were printed. This is one of the dangers of reading a normalized graph.

Comment: @MετάEd, I would call that an improperly normalized, and misleading, graph.  Good to know about this foible of Ngram Viewer; thanks.

Comment: The normalization is helpful for frequently used words; you can see how the frequency varies over time. The difficulty is with words which are used very infrequently.

Comment: Thank you for the edit to #1. You do not need to credit. Notice I am also saying that in your #2 the chart actually bears up OED's scholarship rather than contradicting it.

Comment: Digging around in #2, that is not clear to me, so far.  I haven't found support for OED's claim yet.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding how you think the #2 chart disagrees with OED. You say OED originates the word "todger" in the 1950s; there is a spike on your chart in the mid 1950s. As for the sole earlier spike in 1891, that is an OCR error. So I am left wondering how your chart in any way contradicts OED's conclusion, when actually it seems to bear it up.

Comment: @MετάEd, if you zoom into 1954-1956 (the "spike is 1955"), none of the results use "todger" in the modern way.  Except, maybe some references to a decades-earlier play that uses "Todger Fairmile o Balls Pond" as a suggestive character name (G.B. Shaw, 1917-ish).

Comment: +1 I didn't finish reading the question, yet. Plus 1 for the research alone. :) All that needs to be said now is that too much dependence on nGrams is hazardous. I always cautioned against that. They can only be used to seed a research, help, or support an otherwise stronger research methodology.

Comment: @Kris, Thanks! And I did learn of some dangers, of Google's tools, with this question. :(   PS: I now have a wild theory that "todger" comes from "tadger" and was based off a Dickens character.

Comment: I would have guessed *todger* was in part a play on *roger/rodger* both for nicknames and other uses

Comment: @BrockAdams The lack of a spike at 1955 in Google Book Search (Ngram Viewer) does nothing to call the OED's research into question. (Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.) OED cites its sources. If you have doubts, verify them. If the OED source for the 1950s doesn't exist, *then* you've got something.

Comment: I used to drink a real ale in Whitby N. Yorks in the early 1990s called 'Todgers Old Scrotum!'ABV 6.9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *Todger*, from northern English *tadger*

The OED says *todger* is British slang, a variant of tadger, and their first citation is 1986:

> 1986 Comic Relief Christmas Bk. 135/2
>   Shakespeare uses Comic Relief..to relieve the
>   audience from tragedy with cunning allusions to
>   the enormous todgers that were the joy of his
>   private life.

For *tadger*, they say it's British slang originally from northern England. The etymological origin is unknown but they point out their first quote and a later quote:

> 1949 E. Partridge Dict. Slang (ed. 3) 1192/2
>   Tadger, penis: North Country, esp. Yorkshire...
>   Perh. ex tadpole.
>
> 1990 T. Thorne Bloomsbury Dict. Contemp. Slang
>   (1991) 506/1 Tadger,..a vulgarism of unknown origin (prob. from a lost dialect verb), used for
>   many years in the North of England and revived by
>   students, alternative comedians, etc. in the
>   1980s. Todger is an alternative modern version.

---

### *Tadge*, to beat to a pulp

However, the *New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* (2008) says:

> **todger** *noun* the penis. From the obsolete verb ‘todge’ (to smash to
>   a pulp), the penis seen as a smashing tool *UK, 2001*
>
> **tadger** *noun* the penis. Originally dialect; survives in rhyming slang
>   FOX AND BADGER *UK, 1961*

The obsolete verb *todge* is found in *Slang and Colloquial English* by John S. Farmer and W. E. Henley (1921, New York):

Todge. Stodge : as verb, to smash, to pulp.

And likewise in the *Vocabulum; or The Rogue's Lexicon* by George W. Matsell (1859, New York):

> [image: TODGE. To smash. "Todge the bloke and pad," smoke the man and run.]

It's defined as a noun in Francis Grose's 1785 *[A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue](http://books.google.fi/books?id=zLAJs0_prpwC&pg=PT200&dq=%22todge%20it%22%20%20-%22brother%20tadger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D8ZGUemtIYWl4ATNy4CQAg&redir_esc=y)*:

> [image: Todge, beat all to a todge, said of any thing beat to mash]

---

### *Todger*, Yorkshire dialect for a child?

*Todger* may also have been Yorkshire dialect for a child, judging by the title of a poem by Gwen Wade (1904-1996), a "distinguished Yorkshire Dialect Society member". *[Transactions of the Yorkshire Dialect Society](http://books.google.com/books?id=H8NZAAAAMAAJ)* - Volumes 15-17, 1984:

> Modern Yorkshire dialect poets such as Bill Cowley in his "April Bairn" or Gwen Wade in her **"T'Little Todger"** come closer to black American dialect writers' treatment of children. They write almost exclusively about the delight children give us, or they write "teasing" poems for the children themselves (to scare them into obedience?).

Here's an extract:

> **T'LITTLE TODGER**
>   By gow, but tha sewerly is cappin
>   Thro thi heead dahn to t' soles o' thi feet!
>   Ah could credit at t'Dobs caught us nappin
>   An slipped us a fresh un bi neet;
>   We'd waited on summat o' mettle
>   Bein born o' th o' thi mother an me,
>   But, peeakin up theer on t'langsettle,
>   Why, sitha, tha's thee!

---

### Other snippets

A snippet of *[Mixer and Server](http://books.google.fi/books?id=OcyfAAAAMAAJ&q=tadger%20-%22brother%20tadger%22&dq=tadger%20-%22brother%20tadger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jjRGUaHjJ4Os4ASio4CICQ&redir_esc=y)* (Volume 35, Hotel and Restaurant Employees' International Alliance and Bartenders' International League of America, 1926) uses "little tadger" to refer to a boy.

> Seeing the little tadger trying to reach the bell and thinking he was a good scout and doing his daily good turn, he walked up to the porch, smiled at the youngster and said, "What can I do for you, young man?"

Perhaps less relevant, but a snippet of *[The semantic development of words for "walk, run" in the Germanic languages](http://books.google.fi/books?id=nE8GAQAAIAAJ&q=todge%20%20-%22brother%20tadger%22&dq=todge%20%20-%22brother%20tadger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XTlGUezcDbL14QSaioHwCQ&redir_esc=y)* by Roscoe Myrl Ihrig (University of Chicago press, 1916) offers *todgey* meaning "short and fat":

> [image: 29.32. NE. dial. todge go at a slow, ambling pace; shamble, sb. anything of thick 'stodgy' consistency, as thick soup, todgey short and fat.]

Comment: I wonder why my Concise OED gives a different date.  Are you using the online OED?

Comment: Yes, and both are new entries (OED Third Edition, March 2004). There's also a 1974 Monty Python quotation: "Cut to Arctic wastes—ice
and snow and bitter blasting winds. Carpenter— his little tadger tiny as a tapir's tits—struggles on."

Comment: Okay, so it looks like "todger" likely came from "tadger" (good for my C. Dickens conjecture).  Makes sense that Monty Python might be responsible for its modern resurgence/popularity.

Comment: The nickname Todger for Thomas/Todd is earlier, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Todger) has 1905 and 1917 quotations. But perhaps there's some connection between Tadger/Todger, John Thomas and Roger.

Comment: Great ETA.  The "Smash" and "pulp" stuff, especially.  I'd upvote twice, if the site let me!